# Web deploy package and assembly versions

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, visual-studio-2012, web-deployment, msdeploy

I have one project that is consisted of 3 different projects/assemblies (Data Access layer, Business Layer and Web Application). I am using Visual studio 2012 and the Publish As Web Deploy Package option. In the product that is constructed after publishing i get the required files and using the msdeploy.exe i install the web site to the IIS. Now, the web site in his bin folder has all of the required references(dll's - businesslayer.dll, datalayer.dll).

At first this is scenario is successful. But later i would like to do the following. If i change the assembly file version on some of the dll's, and recompile and republish the website, and re-execute the msdeploy operation, only the dll's with the new assembly information would get updated on the IIS. Is this even posible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDeploy already handles that for you. When you deploy, only the files that are changes are uploaded.

From Kristina Olson from the IIS team:

> Web Deploy does its incremental sync in 2 parts, so in 1st part it sends just metadata about the file content in the package to determine which files actually need updating, so that in 2nd part only those incremental update files are sent over the wire. Basically metadata about every file (things like name, size, write-time) is sent over the wire, but the actual file content is not unless the file needs updating